# Calling dispose() on JxBrowser Browser object sometimes blocks indefinitely in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

Currently diagnosing a bug we've identified in a Swing application using JxBrowser 6.14.2. On load, it creates a new lightweight Browser instance, then adds a few listeners for things like touchscreen compatibility. Whenever the parent window is closed, we call dispose() on the browser object before closing the window. 99% of the time, this works as intended. Occasionally, when quickly closing/opening the window, dispose() causes the entire application to lock up. I looked at a thread dump and found that SocketChannel.waitForPendingPostRequests() is the culprit, as there are Message objects in whatever queue SocketChannel uses that never get removed. The message in the queue is always a GetDocumentMessage or GetDocumentElementMessage, which lead me back to the method that adds our touchscreen listeners after instantiating the browser. I am unable to replicate this issue if I remove our listener method (and the almost identical removeClickListener):

```
private void addClickListener(Browser browser) {
    if (!browser.isDisposed()) {
        DOMDocument doc = browser.getDocument();
        if (doc != null && doc.getDocumentElement() != null) {
            doc.getDocumentElement().addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, clickListener, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Given that we need the ability to both instantiate and dispose of the browser object at will, is there a safe way to add these listeners after creating a new instance of the Browser, or is there a way to clear the SocketChannel queue before calling dispose()?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check whether the same behavior is reproducible with the latest version of JxBrowser? In addition, could you please specify whether your application removes the configured listeners before disposing the Browser instance?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will try on the latest version of JxBrowser and let you know how that goes. I can confirm the application removes all listeners before disposing the Browser instance.

Comment: Updating to 6.18 fixed the issue. Thank you!